# django REST framework api without using models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest framework. In my project i need to send api on a request, here i'm not using model data instead i want to send a dictionary as api response which is read from external database like mongodb. how to do this?

viewset code

```
class LivedataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LiveData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LiveDataSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        user_id = str(self.request.query_params.get('user'))
        if user_id:
            queryset = qs.filter(user=user_id)
            return queryset
        else:
            return qs
```

and serializer code is

```
class LiveDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LiveData
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'status')
```

this code works but it uses model here i need same function without model.

Answer (score 2):

You need `APIView` instead of `ModelViewSet`, with that you can define your own endpoints, without tying it to a model.

Docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/